# Special relativity paradox involving two light clocks

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation, thought-experiment

[image: Train moving quickly]

I came up with this thought experiment that seems to exemplify a paradox. In this paradox, one clock is ticking unevenly for one observer and evenly for another.

Essentially, the clocks record a “tick” each time the light reaches a mirror. There is a light clock in the standard arrangement perpendicular to the motion and a second light clock arranged parallel to the motion. In the parallel light clock it takes more time for the light to go forward than backward. So it seems like one light clock ticks evenly and the other ticks unevenly.

I created a diagram to explain the paradox. I can't figure out the error in my logic. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hello Jacques. This is demonstrating the affects of special rel. Why is it impossible? What do you think is actually happening?

Comment: Conventionally in diagrams North-South is used for Up-Down and West-East for Left-Right.  It's just adding potential confusion when you don't do that.

Comment: If you ignore the fact that the lightclock tick recorders are connected to lightclocks and you just treat the hands of the clock as moving objects, the two clock hands are moving evenly and in sync from the perspective of person A and so they should also be moving in sync for person B. But if you consider that one of them is connected to a horizontal lightclock, then the situation changes. That's where I'm having trouble.

Comment: "And so" is not an argument.

Comment: We've established that the light is hitting the right lightclock mirrors evenly from the perspective of person A but not from the perspective of person B. Let's say I disconnected the right lightclock tick recorder from the right lightlock and I attached it to the left lightclock instead. From the perspective of person A, nothing has changed since the right lightclock tick recorder is still ticking evenly. But now, from the perspective of person B, it is also ticking evenly. My paradox is: how can equivalent motion from one frame translate to different motion in another frame?

Comment: I figured it out! I forgot to take into account the fact that a signal has to travel from the horizontal lightclock to the lightclock tick recorder and the time for this signal to reach the lightclock tick recorder can depend on which mirror is hit. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 5):

Typically we would not consider each mirror to constitute a “tick” but rather a full round trip. However, that is rather minor and is just a small semantic issue.

In principle your analysis is correct. The effect you have noted is due to the relativity of simultaneity. Indeed, the time between the rear and the front tick is different than the time between the front tick and the rear tick in the frame where the horizontal clock is moving. (With a “tick” defined your way)

The relativity of simultaneity is the most challenging concept for new students of relativity to grasp. Hence it is the source of most of the relativistic paradoxes that you will find. In the frame where the light clock is stationary the ticks are even, and in the frame where it is moving the ticks are not. This requires the relativity of simultaneity as neither time dilation nor length contraction can produce this effect.

Comment: I agree that the ticks of the horizontal lightclocks should be uneven from the perspective of person B. What I'm having trouble with is the fact that the hands of the lightclock tick recorders are moving in sync for person A. From person's A perspective, it doesn't matter if the lightclock tick recorders are connected to vertical or horizontal lightclocks, the motion of the hands is the same. From that logic, it shouldn't matter for person B either.

Comment: Notice your use of the word “moving in sync”. Sync is short for synchronization. The relativity of simultaneity is precisely the realization that things which are synchronized in one frame are not synchronized in another frame. You say “from that logic” but that logic is actually just an incorrect assumption. If you work through the logic from the two postulates you find that they cannot be synchronized. The horizontal one must “tick” unevenly with your definition of ticking

Comment: If I had omitted to say what exactly the tick recording devices are measuring and I just presented them as clocks that are moving in sync from the perspective of person A, the logical conclusion is that they would be moving in sync from the perspective of person B. I should be able to calculate how person B perceives the tick recording devices by knowing their motion over time from the perspective of person A, regardless of what is making them tick.

Comment: It does not matter in the least the mechanism of the ticking. The light clock is simply the easiest clock to analyze. But regardless, all clocks will show all relativistic effects, including the relativity of simultaneity. The desynchronization is not due to the structure of the clocks, it is a feature of spacetime. It can be found in the Lorentz transform which governs any clock and all local physical processes.

Comment: The right clock tick recorder is stationary from the perspective of person A. The ticks happening at its location are at a regular interval from the perspective of person A. if the tick recorder was simply a ball moving vertically up by 1 cm at every tick, you could plot the ball in spacetime from the perspective of person A and apply a lorentz transformation and the result shows that the ball would be moving at regular intervals from the perspective of person B.

Comment: I figured it out! I forgot to take into account the fact that a signal has to travel from the horizontal lightclock to the lightclock tick recorder and the time for this signal to reach the lightclock tick recorder can depend on which mirror is hit. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Dale's answer is right.  Here is a little more detail:

Let's set the clocks right next to each other, so that the bottom of Clock 1 coincides with the left end of Clock 2.  Let's conveniently make each clock one light-second long.

When the clocks start, light leaves the origin in both the up and rightward directions.  In the train frame, the first tick of the vertical clock occurs at $(t=0,x=1,y=0)$ and the first tick of the second clock occurs at $(t=1,x=0,y=1)$.  Lorentz transform these and you'll find that in the platform frame, these ticks occur at $t'=(1-xv)/\sqrt{1-v^2}$ and $t'=1/\sqrt{1-v^2}$.  These are not the same so the ticks in the platform frame are not simultaneous.

The second ticks both occur at $(t=2,x=0,y=0)$.  Because these are the same point in spacetime, you don't have to do any arithmetic to know the coordinates will transform identically to the platform frame.

The fact that the first (and third and fifth and seventh....) ticks are out of synch in the platform frame generally makes them inconvenient for illustrating various simple points.  The fact that the second (and fourth and sixth and eighth...) ticks are simultaneous in both frames (together with the fact that they obviously **have** to be simultaneous even before you get into any details) makes them very convenient illustrating those same points.

Comment: You've elegantly demonstrated that the ticks are uneven. My paradox comes from the fact that the motion of the hand of the right lightclock tick recorder is even in one frame and uneven in another even though the motion of the hand of the left lightclock tick recorder is even in both frames.

Comment: What's paradoxical about that?

Comment: What drives the tick recording device determines whether or not it ticks smoothly from the perspective of person B. If I had omitted to say what exactly the tick recording devices are measuring and I just presented them as clocks that are moving in sync from the perspective of person A, the logical conclusion is that they would be moving in sync from the perspective of person B.

Comment: I figured it out! I forgot to take into account the fact that a signal has to travel from the horizontal lightclock to the lightclock tick recorder and the time for this signal to reach the lightclock tick recorder can depend on which mirror is hit. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

The size of your clock is important. If  the size of the clock is effectively zero, there is no problem. A clock of size zero is one based on local events, such as detecting light at a fixed location (the clock in which the light moves back and forth qualifies as a zero size clock). If your clock ticks in the way you defined it, then it is not based on local events, but on events happening at different locations. This happens in the "every other tick" that you defined, your clock will have an error equal to the lack of synchronicity between clocks located at these two different positions.

The reason is that each tick in your clock will measure the time of a different zero sized clock,  these different clocks are the zero-size clocks located at the two ends of the finite sized clock. So it is not surprising that your clock does not tick uniformly. It is effectively ticking in synchrony with clocks located at different locations on alternating ticks. Because these clocks are out of sync, it looks as "non-uniform" ticks in your clock. Thus any finite clock will have an error accounting for this lack of synchrony of ideal clocks located at its different parts.

Answer (score -1):

I can't be certain with my answer as I am not a scientist, but in the scenario the light only becomes uneven when the train increases or decreases speed. Person A would not see this affect as they are part of the increase or decrease in speed, however the onlooker person B would see this because they are traveling at a different speed. This scenario describes the idea that your speed determines your time.

Farther information on this topic can be found at [https://www.space.com/36273-theory-special-relativity.html#:~:text=One%20of%20the%20many%20implications,when%20it%20is%20at%20rest](https://www.space.com/36273-theory-special-relativity.html#:%7E:text=One%20of%20the%20many%20implications,when%20it%20is%20at%20rest).

Comment: As Dale explains, if the two clocks are synchronised in A's frame they are out of synch in B's frame, if the relative velocity between A and B isn't zero. That happens even if the velocity is constant.

Answer (score -2):

Congratulations, you have discovered an example that the speed of light is not isotropic by Einstein's theory, despite the claim .
Another point is that the light clocks in motion, oriented perpendicular to motion (y- and z-axis, in both positive and negative directions), all run synchronously, and that non-simultaneity only exists in one direction.
Usually this is glossed over by assuming that the ticks are evened out between the clocks, despite the obvious difference in this description to the mathematics.
Maybe you would be less likely to be confused about this if you knew that these clocks only tick at the same rate when a mirror is added, and that clocks aligned perpendicular to each other tick at the same rate, eventually, because they invented length contraction.
Without length contraction clocks will never run at the same rate, and since assuming just the second postulate contradicts the first postulate, since the clocks tick at different rates, you can combine your acute observation, with the fudge factor of invented length contraction, and realize the theory is worthless as a description of reality.
Without length contraction, the two postulates of special relativity contradict each other, all other weirdness aside.