# Hidden variable special relativity paradox

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation, thought-experiment

Members of this community were kind enough to contribute to my last paradox post:

[Special relativity paradox involving two light clocks](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/583067/special-relativity-paradox-involving-two-light-clocks)

I'm creating this new post to address the issues raised in that post by providing a new paradox based on the previous one.
[image: golf ball nudged]

However, if you add information to the problem, you can come up with the opposite conclusion. the clock records a “tick” each time the light reaches a mirror:
[image: Extra information]

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand. In your second image, you're measuring a "tick" occurring when the light hits *either* mirror? That doesn't measure "time" though. If you want to associate the ticks with time, you need to compare the time intervals between the light hitting the *same* mirror. Do you agree that this quantity would not be "uneven"?

Comment: Yes, when the light is hitting either mirror. And you're right, that's a terrible clock. At the moment, I'm only interested in how evenly it ticks in different frames of reference.

Comment: Nono, I mean the ticks being uneven doesn't mean that time is flowing unevenly. If you could show that the ticks between light hitting the *same* mirror was uneven, then you would have shown what you want to show. Does that make sense?

Comment: I've modified the post to try and address the issue you've raised by removing all mention of clocks. Does your issue still stand?

Comment: I think you have distinguish between what an observer actually 'sees' and what an observer 'deduces' (having taken the flight-time of the light into consideration)

Comment: @JacquesLeNormand Nice edit, it had me a little stumped for a bit, but it actually helps you answer your own question yourself ;) You see, the "nudging of the golf ball" and the light hitting the mirror are only simultaneous in the rest frame, not in any other frame! :) I'll formulate it a bit better as an answer when I have a little more time :)

Comment: Roger and Philip's comment has shed light on the solution. The golf ball will actually be moving at regular intervals from the perspective of person B assuming the golf ball is equidistant from both mirrors from the perspective of person A. I forgot to take into account the fact that a signal has to travel from the horizontal lightclock to the golf ball and that, from the perspective of person B, this signal takes a different amount of time depending on which mirror is hit.

Comment: @JacquesLeNormand Good attempt! But I think it's a little deeper than that, too. Even if the golf ball were kept equidistant from both mirrors, person B would not "see" (by which I mean deduce) that the golf ball and the "ticks" are synchronised. Two events need to occur simultaneously at the *same* location for everyone to agree upon them. So if instead the golf-ball was place on top of one of the mirrors, and it was moved up every time light hit *that* mirror, then person B would see it as being moved evenly, I think.

Comment: the light from the far mirror does not reach the ball until the light is back to the near mirror, what triggers the motion of the ball?

Answer (score 2):

You're assuming that the nudging of the golf ball and the bouncing of the light are simultaneous with respect to the rest frame of A and the rest frame of B. That isn't possible, just like $x>y$ and $y>x$ isn't possible. You'll have to change your assumptions.

It would be logically consistent to assert that they're simultaneous with respect to only one frame, but that would mean that the nudging and the bouncing are independent events, since there can't be any faster-than-light communication between them.

If the nudging is supposed to happen in response to the bouncing, then there has to be a signal between them. If the signal speed is $c$, then signals from both mirrors will reach the ball at the same time, so it'll be nudged twice in quick succession at regular intervals. For most sublight speeds, the nudging will happen unevenly (with respect to any frame), but if the speed is, say, $\frac12c$ wrt the rest frame of A (and therefore $\frac45c$ wrt the rest frame of B), then the nudging will happen at even intervals (with respect to any frame).

Comment: This, of course, is one of the non-intuitive claims which relativity makes.  Simultaneity is not something you can assume in all frames.  Unlike Newtonian physics, in the world of relativity, two events can be simultaneous in one frame and not simultanious in another.

Answer (score 0):

So if you placed the ball at the center of the light clock, then, yes, person B would see the ball nudged uniformly, but it would occur before the the leading bounce and after the trailing bounce. He would also see the time between leading bounce to training bounce be shorter than the time from trailing bounce to leading bounce.

Answer (score 0):

Typically we would not consider each mirror to constitute a “tick” but rather a full round trip. However, that is rather minor and is just a small semantic issue.

The resolution to this paradox is that the nudging of the golf ball cannot be simultaneous with the “ticking” of your horizontal light clock in all frames. Again, as with your previous paradox (and most special relativity paradoxes) this is due to the relativity of simultaneity.

The relativity of simultaneity says that different reference frames will disagree about the simultaneity of events that are spatially separated in the direction of the relative velocity.

So in this scenario the ball will nudge upward at evenly spaced time intervals in all frames, but the nudging will not be simultaneous with both the front and back ticks in a frame where the train is moving.

Answer (score 0):

This is primarily a response to one of your comments, but is a tad too long to fit in a comment box.  You wrote:

> I forgot to take into account the fact that a signal has to travel from the horizontal lightclock to the golf ball and that, from the perspective of person B, this signal takes a different amount of time depending on which mirror is hit.

No, this is not relevant at all.  You assumed that (presumably in A's frame) the ball nudges up simultaneously with the light hitting the mirrors.  You did **not** assume that the nudging is **caused** by the light hitting the mirrors.  So the time it takes a signal to get from the mirror to the ball is quite irrelevant.  It can be pure coincidence that the light-hitting-the-mirror and the ball-nudging-up are simultaneous, and your alleged "paradox" remains unchanged.

The resolution of course is that what's simultaneous in A's frame is not simultaneous in B's.  In B's frame, first the ball nudges up, then the light hits the right-hand mirror, then the light hits the left-hand mirror (or actually vice versa if B is located to the right of the ball as you've drawn him).